# Dark matter composition

Tags: standard-model, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model

I assume that dark matter is made  of heavy neutrinos.But wouldnt they be converted into neutrinos with less mass throygh weak interaction?So dark matter isnt made of neutrinos.I think there is truly a new fundamental particle a fermion we havent detected yet a dark 
   particle with 0 charge and with a magnetic moment of 0.

Comment: For the three neutrinos we have, muon neutrinos don't decay into electron neutrinos; they oscillate. This is because each variety of neutrino is made up of mass eigenstates, and the heavier eigenstates don't decay into the light eigenstates.

Comment: Yes because they have pretty much the same mass.

Comment: And only by measurement we can understand if a neutrino is an electron neutrino,tau neutrino or muon neutrino.I am saying a hypothetical neutrino with a mass of a quark.

Comment: There are conserved quantities in physics. This is why protons don't decay to positrons (baryon number conservation, lepton number conservation, etc..) Conserved quantities could explain why super-heavy neutrinos don't decay to standard neutrinos.

Comment: Baryons are not converted into leptons because the decay can happen between "similar particles".Super heavy neutrinos are practically a lepton so it will decay into a neutrino.

Comment: The most promising candidate for dark matter is a type of dark quark with 0 charge and when it interacts with other quarks it forces them to become dark quark as well.

Comment: So you've deduced your own rules for physics involving "similar particles" and "pretty much the same mass." This site answers questions using mainstream physics, in which it is believed that conservation rules (and not "having pretty much the same mass") keeps muon neutrinos from decaying into electron neutrinos. We are not going to be able to help you with your own theories of non-mainstream physics. We don't understand them; they're not the theories we learned. See the [help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: ???When I mean similar particles , I mean they are both leptons or they are both quarks.

Comment: And remember some other properties must be conserved as well : mass-energy , charge and angular momentum.

Comment: It's still non-mainstream physics. In mainstream physics, [lepton flavor conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number#Lepton_flavor_conservation) keeps muon neutrinos from decaying to electron neutrinos, and not "having pretty much the same mass".

Comment: Nooo.Lets take beta decay . The electron antineutrino is created due to the conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: Anyway what this has to do with the question.I mean Superman neutrinos dont have different properties than regular neutronos.

Answer (score 1):

As written this isn't exactly a question but if you are trying to ask "what is dark matter made of?" then the answer is no one knows. It is an open research question.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that dark matter is made of heavy neutrinos.

Within the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) there are no heavy neutrinos.  A model beyond the standard model is necessary to posit heavy neutrinos.

One of the models for constituents of dark matter uses [supersymmetry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05259) with R parity conservation. The lightest supersymmetric particle to which R parity conservation constrains supersymmetric parcicles to decay is called [*LSP*, (lightest supersymmetric particle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightest_Supersymmetric_Particle) . Various candidates depending on the specific model are proposed. These  models are a matter of current research. The search for supersymmetry is going on in the LHC data.

> But wouldnt they be converted into neutrinos with less mass throygh weak interaction

No, the LSP cannot decay because of R parity conservation, by construction of the model because it is needed to explain dark matter.

Supersymmetry is beyond the standard model, and also beyond current observations. The LSP will be a new particle, if it is seen in experiments.

Everything about dark matter is under research.

Comment: The susy partners of neutrinos are (scalar) sneutrinos.  The (fermion) neutralinos are susy partners for the neutral weak gauge bosons ($W^0$ and $B$) and higgses.

Comment: @DavidSchaich thanks for the correction

Comment: But neutralinos are bosons.They are force carriers.

Comment: Hmm I see , I dont believe it but anyway thank you.After this post I still believe that dark matter is made of neutrinos.

Comment: Supersymmetry particles havent been detected yet, they only exist in mathematics so I dont believe it

Comment: Or it could be a different type of quarks , dark quarks with 0 charge.

Comment: And when this type of quark interacts with another quark it forces it to become as well a dark quark.

Comment: @Flawless Neutralinos are fermions.  You can start learning about them at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutralino though I recommend that you don't stop there.

Comment: @Flawless  all particles expressed in quantum field theory can be carriers of forces, as described in Feynman diagrams. (Feynman diagrams are recipes for integrals to calculate the probability of interaction or decay.) The gauge bosons are special because they are connected with the basic symmetry and the lowest order particle exchange diagrams.

Comment: Supersymmetric particle of a fermion is a boson:)

Comment: @Flawless as david corrected me, it is the sneutrino that is the boson partner of the neutrino. read his comment where he corrected me.